# How to store and manipulate data with angular, ngrx and redux when some components request same data from server?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I'm using Angular7 with ngrx in my project and I need to fetch and store data for several same components.
For example:

1. I have two (many to many) models Author and Book
2. I have AuthorListComponent which shows some list of AuthorCardComponent.
3. AuthorCardComponent contains "Show best books" button.
4. When user clicks on this button AuthorCardComponent should receive from server best books written by author.

As I understand redux, I need to normalize data i.e.

1. Store all loaded books in one place (books cache)
2. Store all request-response pairs with links to  books cache
3. Keep how many responses contain each book to clear books cache from unused books.
4. All fetching duplicated books from server should be compared with stored instances and be overwritten if some properties differ.

So store looks like this

```
store = {
    authors: {/* .... */},
    books: {
        totalRequests: 3,
        requests: {
            "request1": {
                request: {authorId: 77},
                status: 'done',
                total: 3,
                bookIds: ['15', '99', '101']
            },
            "request2": {
                request: {authorId: 88},
                status: 'loading',
            },
            "request3": {
                request: {authorId: 66},
                status: 'done',
                total: 5,
                bookIds: ['55', '94', '141']
            }
        },
        booksCache: {
            '15': { id: '15', label: '...', /* .... */ },
            '55': { id: '55', label: '...', /* .... */ },
            '94': { id: '94', label: '...', /* .... */ },
            /* ... */
        }
    }         
}
```

It's not so difficult to write all these action creators, reducers, size effects and so on but I have some unsolved questions:

1. How AuthorCardComponent can get proper selector for fetching request status and response data? When AuthorCardComponent calls

```
this.store.dispatch({action: 'BOOKS_GET', payload: {request: {authorId: id}});
```

it doesn't know how to subscribe to own responseN if this response number generated by reducer.

2. How AuthorCardComponent can inform storage that last request is not needed anymore?
3. Is there more simple way to solve problem with keeping books and responses separatly?
4. Is there more suitable state manager instead ngrx/redux?

Comment: Why request/store same data is a problem?

Comment: @DanNguyen When several AuthorCardComponents send requests independently each of them should get only own response. I can store requests as key-value storage but how AuthorCardComponent will know which key to use?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the selector you've created to get the information from the state. It would be something like this:

```
  books$: Observable<BooksStateDetails> = this.store.pipe(
    select(selectBooks)
  );
```

You can use something like the above in each component that needs the data, just select it from the store. You can then use the `async` pipe to display the data, as needed.

The `async` pipe will unsubscribe automatically.

Comment: In this case AuthorCardComponent gets all books state. It should get only own request data but it does't know own request number. I added store structure to make my question more clearly.

Comment: it sounds like you need an AuthorCardDetailComponent that displays the selected book, which is launched from that button in the parent component.

Comment: Each AuthorCardComponent contains own button and receive own list of books and display it on own expand panel.

Comment: I'm not really following without seeing more code - can you put the repo in a stackblitz or something similar?

Comment: Could you, or are you, keeping a list of the requests in the authors state? Say, something like `requests: ['request1', 'request2']` that you could use to tell the books state which requests are no longer needed?